# Java: How to compare UnicastRemoteObject / Remote?

Tags: java, comparison, chat, rmi

i'm writing a dumb "chat" for an University test

i've to use the RMI with rmic and rmiregistry ( old methods )

but i've a strange behaviour comparing Remote objects, for example in this code:

```
public class Server extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ServerIFace {
[...]
private ArrayList<ClientIFace> online;
[...]
public boolean join(ClientIFace client) throws RemoteException {
    synchronized (online) {
        if (online.size() >= MAX_CLIENTS) {
            return false;
        }

        this._sendBroadcast("New User: " + client.getNickname(), null);

        online.add(client);

        [...]
```

Each comparison i do next between the calling client and the online list elements fails:

```
private void _sendBroadcast(String mex, ClientIFace sender)
        throws RemoteException {
    for (ClientIFace c : online) {
        if (c != sender) {
            c.recvMsg(mex);
        }
    }
}
```

The "if (c != sender)" never returns false , but the "sender" is a client
added in online during join.

Am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved : seems that UnicastRemoteObject cannot be compared directly by reference, but equals method has been modified to do this job.

so "c.equals(sender)" will work correctly since it compares references internally in this case